# Spiritual Level of (Melech) HaMoshiach

Tags: messiah

It is often said that Moshiach will be a person at the level of the greatest people in Jewish history (i.e., Moshe/Moses, Dovid/David, etc.), since it says in Yeshayahu (**הִנֵּה יַשְׂכִּיל עַבְדִּי יָרוּם וְנִשָּׂא וְגָבַהּ מְאֹד**).

Now, considering the concept of Yeridas Hadoros (the continuous spiritual decline of the generations), how is it possible to have a person today that is on the level of these people?

One possible answer I thought of is that it may mean that only once Hashem decides that he chooses this person, he will then exalt him, etc, but not that the person himself could reach that spiritual level himself (in other words, not that this person could be that sin-free, righteous, etc., as were the Avos, etc.).

Any thoughts?

Comment: Perhaps the concept of yeridat hadorot is a generality; not an absolute rule. Maybe those who subscribe to the doctrine of yeridat hadorot do not subscribe the the belief that the Messiah will be as great as the prophets.

Comment: Perhaps it means he will fulfill his own potential to the extent those people did, even though that potential will (because of the _dor_ surrounding him, say) be less.